# Why does Rust consider it safe to leak memory?

Tags: pointers, memory-leaks, rust

According to [this chapter in the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-06-reference-cycles.html), it is possible to leak memory by creating a cycle of pointers:

> Rust’s memory safety guarantees make it difficult, but not impossible, to accidentally create memory that is never cleaned up (known as a *memory leak*). Preventing memory leaks entirely is not one of Rust’s guarantees in the same way that disallowing data races at compile time is, meaning memory leaks are memory safe in Rust. We can see that Rust allows memory leaks by using `Rc<T>` and `RefCell<T>`: it’s possible to create references where items refer to each other in a cycle. This creates memory leaks because the reference count of each item in the cycle will never reach 0, and the values will never be dropped.

There exist alternatives like "weak pointers" that would allow you to create self-referential structures that could still be cleaned up when dropped. In fact, using `Weak<T>` is actually suggested later in that chapter.

Why does Rust consider this safe? Why is this an instance where the language does not do anything to prevent 'bad programmer behaviour'?

Comment: Why do you think it should be unsafe to do so? Does it break any guarantees Rust provides? Does it affect the control flow in any way? Is it possible to access the forgotten bytes later in any manner? :)

Comment: Other than the part of the book that you already quoted, I don't think that there is much to say about this. _"memory leaks are memory safe"_ is the right answer.

Comment: @hellow That's the thing: I had expected that 'forgetting' stuff (keeping things around in memory 'forever' without running their destructor) would be undesirable and I was amazed to find out that indeed Rust's guarantees do not talk about this situation, which is the reason I asked this question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Because it is safe.**

---

`unsafe` has a very specific meaning in Rust, it specifically targets classes of programming mistakes which trigger *Undefined Behavior*. Those are the nastiest mistakes, as they completely subvert your whole understanding of a program, allowing either compiler or hardware to behave in unpredictable ways.

Memory leaks do not trigger *Undefined Behavior*, and therefore are safe.

*You may be interested in what the Nomicon (the Unsafe equivalent of the Rust Book) has to say about [Leaking](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/leaking.html); the example about `ScopeGuard` is often referred to as the Leakpocalypse.*

---

It is notable that Garbage Collected languages can easily leak memory, for example. A simple `Map` in which key-value pairs are added without ever being removed will eventually lead to heap exhaustion; and the GC will not be able to stop it.

An ever-growing `Map` is as undesirable as repeatedly forgetting to `free` a pointer, in either case heap exhaustion looms, yet GC'ed languages are considered safe in general.

Comment: Great answer! The Nomicon specifically is more in-depth than I'd ever expect an answer to this question to be :'). I do think that the 'ever growing `Map` is maybe not the best example, however, since while this might end up at some point _depleting_ available memory, it is not 'leaking' it (as soon as the program stops using the map, regardless of how big it has become, it will be reclaimed by the GC). The fact that both instances (the `Map` and unreachable pointers) will at some point trigger heap exhaustion, is definitely interesting...

Comment: I guess that 'heap exhaustion' is a practical problem we encounter when our physical Von Neumann machines are at the limit of their capabilities to simulate a Turing Machine (which, after all, has infinite memory), which means that heap exhaustion is a bad problem _in practice_, but it is  safe _in theory_ because there it cannot happen?

Comment: @Qqwy: (1) Regarding the `Map` memory being reclaimed when the program stops using the map; I would point that most OSes will collect the memory of a process when the program stops as well. In this sense, leaks are always ephemeral. (2) I like your characterization of theory (infinite memory) and practice (finite memory).

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to cause a memory leak in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55553048/155423)

Comment: Note that memory leaks *could* be declared undefined behavior (e.g. with linear types). That is, the people that develop Rust get to define what UB is in the language. Therefore, make sure that you don't also say *"Memory leaks do not cause Undefined Behavior, because they are safe."*  since that would be a cyclical definition.