# How to split a Vec into two without allocating memory?

Tags: vector, memory-management, rust, unsafe, ownership

I am looking for a function similar to [`slice::split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut). Let's name it `split_at` with the signature

```
pub fn split_at<T>(v: Vec<T>, mid: usize) -> (Vec<T>, Vec<T>)
```

such that

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let (first, second) = split_at(v, 2);
assert_eq!(first, vec![1, 2]);
assert_eq!(second, vec![3, 4]);
```

The function should allocate no memory and simply split a vector into two. You don't need to worry about capacity as the resultant vectors will not be modified.

The nightly-only method [`Vec::into_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_raw_parts) seems promising, but I am on the stable release channel which doesn't allow such methods.

Comment: How would the compiler know when to free the allocated memory?

Comment: @Shepmaster Hmmm... haven't really think about that. Perhaps it can reclaim the memory when both `first` and `second` fall out of their scope? Your question reminds me that I probably shouldn't use `Vec::into_raw_parts` even if it is stabilized because `second` might reference a dangling pointer if `first` is dropped before it.

Comment: To detect both going out of scope you'd need some kind of reference counting. Then you are just reinventing [`bytes`](https://crates.io/crates/bytes).

Answer (score 10):

Your request, as phrased, is not possible with a `Vec`. `Vec` represents **unique** ownership of the allocated memory. When a `Vec` goes out of scope, that memory will be deallocated.

If you could do what you ask, then you'd either

1. Deallocate one piece of memory twice (the starting piece of memory)
2. Deallocate a non-allocated piece of memory (somewhere in the middle of the memory)

Both cases are *memory unsafety*, exactly what Rust aims to prevent.

---

You are likely coming from a programming language with a garbage collector, and that's also a way to solve the same problem here.

The [bytes](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.0.1/bytes/struct.BytesMut.html#method.split) crate provides a reference-counted vector-like type called `Bytes` (or `BytesMut` for other circumstances):

```rust
use bytes::Bytes; // 1.0.1

fn main() {
    let v = Bytes::from(vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);
    let (first, second) = v.split_at(2);
    assert_eq!(first, vec![1, 2]);
    assert_eq!(second, vec![3, 4]);
}
```

Comment: Nitpicking: Since `Vec`s live on the heap, it is technically possible to leak the memory, [which is safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107324/why-does-rust-consider-it-safe-to-leak-memory). A memory leak is certainly undesirable. though.

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly what I was looking for, but [`split_off`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.split_off) is close enough.

```
let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
let vec2 = vec.split_off(1);
assert_eq!(vec, [1]);
assert_eq!(vec2, [2, 3]);
```

To answer my own question

```
pub fn split_at<T>(mut v: Vec<T>, mid: usize) -> (Vec<T>, Vec<T>) {
    let remainder = v.split_off(mid);
    (v, remainder)
}
```